# Java + Hibernate : NativeQuery = Truncated incorrect INTEGER value

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Я формирую запрос:

```
em.createNativeQuery("select * from table where :condition")
    .setParameter("condition", condition)
    .executeUpdate;

condition = "channel LIKE CONCAT('%','11111','%')"
```

При выполнении запроса вылетает ошибка:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'channel LIKE CONCAT('%','11111','%')'
```

При этом, если я формирую запрос:

```
em.createNativeQuery("select * from table where channel LIKE CONCAT('%','11111','%')")
    .executeUpdate;
```

Все работает хорошо...
Почему не работает вставка через setParameter() ведь интерфейс для String есть

> Query setParameter(String var1, Object var2);

Чего он на INTEGER ругается?

Comment: потому что должны писать так `em.createNativeQuery("select * from table where channel LIKE CONCAT('%','?1','%')").setParameter("1", 11111).executeUpdate;` setParameter - это метод для позиционных и 
 именованных параметров

Comment: ну так я и использую именнованый параметр

Comment: но мне нужно в параметр вставлять именно строчку `channel LIKE CONCAT('%','11111','%')`

Comment: эта строчка формируется динамически и может быть вида `channel LIKE CONCAT('%','11111','%') OR channel LIKE CONCAT('%','22222','%') OR channel LIKE CONCAT('%','33333','%')` хотя может есть другой способ сформировать такой запрос?

Comment: В общем формирую весь запрос как `String query = "select..."`, а потом `em.createNativeQuery(query).executeUpdate();`